# How to make NewsList from News package show news as list

Tags: c1-cms

I'am calling the NewsList (from the standard Composite.News package) from a template like this:

```
<f:function name="Composite.News.NewsList" xmlns:f="http://www.composite.net/ns/function/1.0"> 
<f:param name="ListOptions" value="Show date,Show teaser" /> 
<f:param name="PageSize" value="10" /> 
<f:param name="DateFormat" value="dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy" /> 
</f:function>
```

I can't make it to show the news as a list. It only shows the first newsitem in the detailsmode.

What does the below line in the NewsList function do?

How can I make the control show my news in a list and not the first (most recent) item?

I have talked to a more experienced Composite Developer and he couldn't either make the Composite.News.Newslist show news in a list.

UPDATE:
I can se that the OMNICORP site doesn't use the standard News package. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Omnicorp Demo Site has its own **News** module based on global data type "Omnicorp.Content.News" and XSLT function "Omnicorp.Content.News"

**Composite.News** package is different and based on page data folder named "Composite.News.NewsItem" and two XSLT functions: "Composite.News.NewsList" and "Composite.News.NewsTeasers". So to use this package you should follow the steps described here - http://docs.composite.net/Packages/CompositeNews: create a page with page type = "News page". Add news item to the News page data folder (under the page). On the Content tab, have the Composite.News.NewsList function, which will render News List with links to the details.

Comment: Ok - but how can I make the NewList show in the aside with paging? I can't make all the news be listed in the content page either

Comment: Note, the News items are attached to the specific page and the function NewsList should be added to the content of this page and only on this page you will see the list of its attached News. You can use function NewsTeasers where you want, it will render links to the resent News Items.

Comment: But can I make the NewsTeasers list all the news and set up paging as well?

Answer (score 0):

*But can I make the NewsTeasers list all the news and set up paging as well?*

Yes you can. You can modify the existent NewsTeaser function or create the new function. On the Function Call tab modify the "Composite.News.NewsItem.GetNewsItemXml" function call and specify next parameters "**PageNumber**" and "**IncludePagingInfo**" with next values:

```
    <f:param name="PageNumber">
        <f:function name="Composite.Web.Request.QueryStringIntegerValue">
            <f:param name="ParameterName" value="Page" />
            <f:param name="FallbackValue" value="1" />
        </f:function>
    </f:param>
    <f:param name="IncludePagingInfo" value="True" />
```

On the function **Template** tab add template to display PagingInfo:

```
<xsl:param name="pagingInfo" select="/in:inputs/in:result[@name='GetNewsItemXml']/PagingInfo" />
```

...

```
            <xsl:if test="$pagingInfo/@TotalPageCount &gt; 1">
                            <div class="Paging">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="$pagingInfo" />
                            </div>
            </xsl:if>
```

...

```
    <xsl:template match="PagingInfo">
    <xsl:param name="page" select="1" />
    <xsl:if test="$page &lt; @TotalPageCount + 1">
        <xsl:if test="$page = @CurrentPageNumber">
            <span><xsl:value-of select="$page" /></span>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not($page = @CurrentPageNumber)">
            <a href="?Page={$page}"><xsl:value-of select="$page" /></a>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
            <xsl:with-param name="page" select="$page+1" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

For more information how to add Paging to the XSLT read this article- http://docs.composite.net/XSLT/SortingAndPaging